# Have a line of javascript being added to the <head> tag of all my domains. Not sure what it is or where it is coming from

Tags: javascript, anonymous-function

I have several domains hosted at one hosting service. All of them have a line of javascript added to the  tag. It appears to be changing Math.random to something else, but I can't figure out what it's trying to accomplish.

I also can't find out where it is coming from. I have mostly WordPress domains, but 2 of my sites are static and the files there haven't been touched in years. They still show this. Also, a Drupal site has this added too.

So, I'm hoping for help with two things: 1) what is it doing? and 2) where is it coming from?

I see it in any browser I use other than the android browser on my phone. I don't see it on other sites except for 1, so I don't believe it to be related to my PC or browser.

This is the script itself. The large number in the arguments to the function call is different every time. I don't know enough about anonymous functions to really sort out what is happening here.

```
<script type="text/javascript">/* <![CDATA[ */Math.random=function(a,c,d,b){return function(){return 300>d++?(a=(1103515245*a+12345)%b,a/b):c()}}(237429089,Math.random,0,1<<21);(function(){function b(){try{if(top.window.location.href==c&&!0!=b.a){var p=document.createElement('a');p.href=c;var len=p.hostname.length;var sep='';var path=p.pathname;if(p.hostname.charAt(len-1)!='/'){sep=(p.pathname.charAt(0)=='/')?'':'/';}else{if(p.pathname.charAt(0)=='/'){path=p.pathname.slice(1);}}c='http%3A%2F%2F'+p.hostname+sep+path+'%2F';var a=-1!=navigator.userAgent.indexOf('MSIE')?new XDomainRequest:new XMLHttpRequest;a.open('GET','http://1.2.3.4/cserver/clientresptime?cid=CID5460105.AID1492092648.TID387&url='+c+'&resptime='+(new Date-d)+'&starttime='+d.valueOf(),!0);a.send(null);b.a=!0}}catch(e){}}var d=new Date,a=window,c=document.location.href,f='undefined';f!=typeof a.attachEvent?a.attachEvent('onload',b):f!=typeof a.addEventListener&&a.addEventListener('load',b,!1)})();/* ]]> */</script>
```

**UPDATE - April 18/17**

I have checked this from other PCs and I still get the inserted javascript. Also, I have found several other sites which have this code in their header. They appear to be WP blogs but not all WP blogs that I check have this.

Comment: You've been hacked. That's likely malware coming from a compromised WordPress or Drupal plugin.

Comment: looks like Difster is right. but please format code readable next time. all in one line isn't readable

Comment: Are you getting this just on your pc or other pcs as well? Might just be a browser plugin

Comment: Thanks Difster. Would this affect non WP sites on the same server?

Comment: Hi TypedSource. That is how the code is inserted into the file. I thought it best to show how it was in the wild, so to speak. I've tried to format it myself but it seems that Optimae has done a wonderful job of it for me.

Comment: Hi Anurag. Good suggestion. I've tested it with IE, Edge and Firefox on my PC and all 3 show the same code. I haven't tested other PCs yet, but will do that after our Easter dinner. My phone (android) doesn't show it, so it may be PC related.

Answer (score 1):

After some questioning in other forums, I was finally able to track down an answer. This is inserted into web pages by the ISP I use (Xplornet here in Canada, Hughesnet in the US) to track response times for their satellite internet acceleration. It only shows up in sites using the http protocol rather than https (they can't inject into those encrypted packets).

I'm not too sure that I'm happy with this since it will use more of my bandwidth for their purposes and they happily charge me when I go over my limit every month. Another great reason to find an new ISP as soon as I can!

But at least it doesn't seem malicious and it's not a problem on my hosting or my PC which is nice.

Thanks to all for helping out with this!

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't  appear to be malicious. Contact your hosting provider to find out if they're inserting it and/or try to find out if their other clients have it too.

It's hard to say but it could be a logging, cache or IE detection tool (MSIE stands for Microsoft Internet Explorer). You'll have to ask them though.

Unminified code:

```
Math.random = function(a, c, d, b) {
    return function() {
        return 300 > d++ ? (a = (1103515245 * a + 12345) % b, a / b) : c()
    }
}(237429089, Math.random, 0, 1 << 21);

(function() {
    function b() {
        try {
            if (top.window.location.href == c && !0 != b.a) {
                var p = document.createElement('a');
                p.href = c;
                var len = p.hostname.length;
                var sep = '';
                var path = p.pathname;
                if (p.hostname.charAt(len - 1) != '/') {
                    sep = (p.pathname.charAt(0) == '/') ? '' : '/';
                } else {
                    if (p.pathname.charAt(0) == '/') {
                        path = p.pathname.slice(1);
                    }
                }
                c = 'http%3A%2F%2F' + p.hostname + sep + path + '%2F';
                var a = -1 != navigator.userAgent.indexOf('MSIE') ? new XDomainRequest : new XMLHttpRequest;
                a.open('GET', 'http://1.2.3.4/cserver/clientresptime?cid=CID5460105.AID1492092648.TID387&url=' + c + '&resptime=' + (new Date - d) + '&starttime=' + d.valueOf(), !0);
                a.send(null);
                b.a = !0
            }
        } catch (e) {}
    }
    var d = new Date,
        a = window,
        c = document.location.href,
        f = 'undefined';
    f != typeof a.attachEvent ? a.attachEvent('onload', b) : f != typeof a.addEventListener && a.addEventListener('load', b, !1)
})(); /* ]]>
```

Comment: Thanks Optimae. It doesn't look malicious to me, but I still don't understand what it is actually doing. I've sent a support request to my hosting provider and they claim not to be adding it. I've found this same script on one other web site that isn't mine, but most of the ones I've tested are clean. The one I've seen it on doesn't appear to be hosted on the same one.